# Jhipster microservice architecture with uaa service, swagger post method, access_denied Invalid CSRF Token

Tags: swagger, jhipster

I generated with jhipster v5.8.2
a uaa service,
a proxy
and a microservice in which I defined a foo entity.

My problem is that when I connect to the proxy and I go on swagger (administration-> api).  and I'm trying to create a new entity foo with the POST method. I get the error 403 Invalid CSRF Token

```
{
   "error": "access_denied",
   "error_description": "Invalid CSRF Token '5c76e875-1f49-4a29-97f2-beacc6082b0e' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'."
}
```

I get the same error for all POST, PUT, DELETE methods.

a solution please

Comment: have you been able to resolve the issue?